# How do I set Java 7 in IBM Domino Designer

Tags: java, ide, version, domino-designer-eclipse

I have an agent in Designer and now I need to make it work. The problem I've encountered is a Java version.. In IDE I've used (IDEA) the Java version is 7 (I use it, cause coding in Eclipse is a nightmare). Now I've tried to put my code in Domino.. And got 30+ "errors", like can not catch multi exceptions, generics, "mismatch", etc.. Although I installed FP9(Fix pack) when I went Project -> Properties -> Java Compiler JDK is still 1.6. My domino version is 9.0.1 and I can not believe, that they didn't update Java since 2006. How can I set JDK and JRE to 7 (if not 8)?

[image: Screen from Domino]

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your Designer to 9.0.1FP9 as that is the first version that uses a newer Java version (1.8). All previous versions use Java 1.6 (9.0.1FP8 started to implement Java 8, but not yet for Designer client).

Take care: All Clients and Servers need to be at least 9.0.1FP8 to be able to run your code.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Java 8 in Designer is scheduled for FixPack 10, isn't it? And I don't expect that in the next couple of months...
But from 9.0.1FP8 onward it should be no problem to export a jar file from any IDE you want and attach it to a script lib (but beware of memory leaks)